# How to determine Callable execution time in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I have tasks that have a timeout limit, I want to determine how much execution time did those tasks get before they were forced to terminate?

e.g. if a task spent all its time waiting on queue because there was no avaialble thread it would have execution time of zero.

Is the best approach to  sub class `ThreadPoolExecutor` and override `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute`, if so, how?

Comment: You can also look into subclassing at Callable level via [`newTaskFor(Callable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor%28java.lang.Runnable,%20T%29) ([ExecutorCompletionService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.java#115) does that for example)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wilddiary.com/tracking-thread-pool-in-java/) is an implementation of a tracking thread pool that tracks cumulative execution statistics of the tasks like total execution time, average execution time, total tasks completed and total in progress tasks.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for. But, this would definitely give you an idea on the implementation and you can modify the implementation to suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Better you can code inside call method itself.

for Ex.

```
call() {
long time = System.currentTimeInmillis();

..
..
//Logic
..
..

long time1 = System.currentTimeInmillis();

//Now you can find the time difference.
}
```

This code wont take waiting time and also it will find only computation time.

Comment: I have eventually resorted to doing just that. But I have a bad feeling that it doesn't cover all cases. For instance, task got cancelled. In addition from a design perspective, I would vote for a more aspect oriented approach